# Not allowed to "Create Facebook Page" for app

Tags: facebook, settings, facebook-apps

I simply want to create a Facebook page that is associated with my app. Here is the problem am having:

- Towards the bottom of my Facebook app's advanced settings, I try to
  ***Create Facebook Page.***
- It states *"This will create a new community Facebook Page and
  associate it with this app. Are you sure you want to continue?"*
- I click 'Confirm' and then it says *"Creating content with this name
  is not allowed. Try another name."*
- I suspect this is because my App Display Name is *'zuChat'* (I've read that it has to be proper-case), however, the textbox to change the name is disabled.

Why am I unable to change the name, and is this even the problem with creating the facebook page?

Answer (score 2):

Just change your app's display name to all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, I had to put first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase. For your app it would be "Zuchat".

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that FB will not allow me to create a page where the page name includes the word "App".